# delete batch script not working

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF

Set LOG="C:\Temp\Copy_Delete.log"

::##############################################
::Begin Deleting 
::##############################################


Set Sourcedir="C:\test"

Echo %date% %time%: "Deleting from %sourcedir% >> %LOG%

FORFILES /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c del @path %Sourcedir%" >> %LOG%
```

When i executed this ,delete didn't work and in the log file it shows 
C:\test*, Are you sure (Y/N)? and at the command prompt it gives this message "Fri 11/08/2013 16:11:43.28: "Deleting from "C:\test" >> "C:\Temp\Copy_Delete.log"
what could be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing quiet flag to del command.

```
del /Q @path %Sourcedir%" >> %LOG%
```

Comment: i used the above command and executed the script .got bleow message Fri 11/08/2013 17:08:14.39: "Deleting from "C:\test" >> "C:\Temp\Copy_Delete.log
"
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: delete didn't work and the log file gives the Y/N option. is there anything i need to change in the forfiles script

Comment: I would also like to get the name of the files deleted from the c:\test folder in the logfile . is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Is your bat file located in the same folder which you are trying to clean? If yes then obviously that you cannot delete it because you are running it. Also try to run script using "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

This worked under Windows 7 Pro:

```
@ECHO OFF

Set LOG="C:\Temp\Copy_Delete.log"

::##############################################
::Begin Deleting 
::##############################################


Set Sourcedir="C:\test"

Echo %date% %time%: Deleting from %sourcedir% >> %LOG%

FORFILES /P "%Sourcedir%" /D +0 /C "cmd /c IF @ISDIR==FALSE DEL @path" >> %LOG%
```

It deletes all files modified today in C:\test .

Comment: getting this error after executing the script.                    The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: You have files in `c:\test` that are open in another program.

Comment: In C:\test, you have files opened with .Lock mechanism, such as Word, Access, IIS log files?